# Determining cell designations of values in Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I am automating a set of Excel sheets that performs complex calculations. To unit test, I am asserting equality between the Python output and the Excel output. However, the cell designations (ex. `A5`, `B26`) of the Excel outputs vary between sheets, but the naming is the same. For example, this section appears on every spreadsheet but in different locations

**How would I approach writing code to extract this table's cell designation from an Excel sheet?**

| ... | ... |
| --- | --- |
| Final Output: |  |
| Year 1 | 100 000 |
| Year 2 | 150 000 |
| Year 3 | 200 000 |
| ... | ... |

**What I've done**

So far I have used `pandas.read_excel()` to create a data frame of the entire sheet, added a header with the column letters (i.e: `A, B, C, ...`), and am treating the indexes as the row numbers (i.e: `1, 2, 3, ...`). The issue is that `pandas.read_excel(`) automatically skips blank lines and the `skip_blank_lines = False` feature has been depreciated, so the row numbers are inaccurate (as there are blank lines in the file that also vary between spreadsheets).

The reason I need the cell designations is that I plan to modify the 'input' cell values via `openpyxl` to vary the Excel outputs and test a greater amount of cases.

**Constraint:** I am unable to modify the spreadsheets.

Please advise on any tips if you think of a better way to unit test Python output against an Excel spreadsheet's output.

Comment: My bad, my focus was to ask a generic question (how to get cell designations) but I placed too much emphasis on the example. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Regardless, what I said in my comment still applies — it was a generic answer describing how to get them from any Excel file.

Comment: Please include some code.

Comment: @CharlieClark What code do you want to see? Here is what I'm using: `ws = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = "...", usecols = "...", nrows = "...")` and `ws = ws.loc[ws['...'] = '...'].index[0]` to get the row number but because `pd.read_excel()` skips blank lines, the row number is incorrect

Comment: Please include any code in your question not in the comments.

Comment: What code do you want to see? I don't believe my question requires me to share code

Comment: @Ben: You're mistaken about that.

Comment: I'm confused what code I'm expected to share. My project has thousands of lines of code and sharing code would make the question more tailored (ie. opinionated) to my own situation, which would result in the question being closed

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're attempting to achieve so I may be way off; would it be more useful to you to just extract the table ranges and work with that?  e.g. {'Table1': 'B2:F15', 'Table2': 'K14:L19', 'Data5_9': 'D23:E26', 'Table3': 'H23:J27'}

Comment: @Ben: You're expected to provide a [mre] — we don't want to see all your code.

Comment: @moken The objective is to extract those cell ranges using without having to open each spreadsheet (which is Plan B). The reason for this is that there are over a hundred sheets, each with dozens of different input parameters. We know those input parameters and want to look for them and find their cell values